# How to get parameter with special characters in angular routing

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, web-frontend

Here is my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'file-view/:file_name', component: FileViewComponent },];
```

My template

```
<div *ngFor="let el of mapElement['fileItems']| filter:term">
    <a href="file-view/{{el['fileName']}}">
       <p>{{el['fileName'] }} ({{el['number']}})</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is to get value of file_name

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('file_name');
}
```

When I try to access a endpoint "http://localhost:4200/file-view/?CSTARTUP%20(cstartup.r87)" from template anchor tag

Here, if the file_name parameter has any special characters it fails to capture it. It works for simple string like this "**cstartup.r87**" But I'm trying to get something like this "**?CSTARTUP (cstartup.r87)**" and it fails.
How can I cpature whole as a string here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using this function to encode fileName.

```
encodeUriAll(value: string) {
return value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, c =>
  `%${c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()}`
);}
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#encoding_for_content-disposition_and_link_headers)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It's a very bad practice to use special characters in a **routes name**. So if you need special characters use query params as example. [Here](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html#:%7E:text=Query%20strings,applied%20to%20the%20original%20object.) you can read all about the html uri schema.

Your problem is the question mark. Why? In a standard html path a question mark (?) tell the browser: *Hey, here is a query param*. So Angular (or pure JS, too) cannot handle it.

If you need the question mark let Angular do this with the **Router**. So don't use *href* in a `<a></a>`. Try this one:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/userdetails']" [queryParams]="{ id: '?CSTARTUP'}">User Details with query parameter</a>

<a [routerLink]="['/other']" [queryParams]="{ id: '?asdF.123'}">User Details with query parameter</a>
```

Inside `.ts` you can use `router.navigate([....])` and set the query params like this:

```
 this.router.navigate(
    ['/other'],
    { queryParams: { id: '?asdF.123' } }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalence of encoding the uri to something the program can read, you should always use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` when sending text if you don't rely on ready made code.